# Wrappers in Android for unlocking Android Games levels

Tags: android, wrapper

I am new to Android development. I want to create a wrapper in my Android game so that after a certain level the game will lock. The user will then have to send an SMS to unlock that level and able to play it.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad -- what have you tried already and where are you stuck?

Comment: I am new in android , i have searched related topics on wrapper but hard luck.can you suggest any docs or tutorials where i can get idea about wrappers???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an own broadcast wich is send after starting each level.
Then u could catch this broadcast (check conditions) and set a global variable to "lock" or "unlock".

(Otherwise u can just use simple SharedPreferences to save the lastest (un)lock-state wich u check before every level...)

Comment: Thanks Thomas , can you give me any link or docs,tutorials which can brief me about wrappers.